# make a video from all png images from a folder based on numerical order?

Tags: matlab, sorting, image-processing

I am tryign to make a video from png files, and they should be in the order while when it make the video, it put image test_1, next test_10, but I need to be 
test_1, test_2, test_3.... 
if I sort them by %sort_nat({images.name}); I will get an error later Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
any comment would apprecited. 
here is script:

```
clear all; clc;close all;
path = 'D:/Neda/Pytorch/U-net/plots_U_Net/CineLoop';
filePattern = fullfile(path, '*.png');
imgfileattrib = dir(filePattern); %attributes
images = {imgfileattrib.name};    %list of images
[~, ind] = sort(str2double(regexprep(images,'[^0-99]',''))); %sorted indices
images = images(ind);             

writerObj = VideoWriter('YourAVI.avi');
writerObj.FrameRate=1;
open(writerObj);

for frameNumber = 1 : length(images)

     baseFileName = images(frameNumber);
     fullFileName = fullfile(path, baseFileName);

     fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
     thisimage = imread(fullFileName);
     imshow(thisimage);  
     drawnow; 
     writeVideo(writerObj, thisimage);
end
close(writerObj);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Remove](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) non-numeric characters, [convert to double](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) and then apply [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) to get the correctly sorted indices. Use these indices to sort `images`.

```
imgfileattrib = dir(filePattern); %attributes
images = {imgfileattrib.name};    %list of images
[~, ind] = sort(str2double(regexprep(images,'[^0-9]',''))); %sorted indices
images = images(ind);             %sorted list
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. it's causing an error "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type." which is because images = {imgfileattrib.name};    %list of images

Comment: @Neda You should be using `baseFileName` instead of `baseFileName.name` and then you haven't defined `fullFileName`. I assume you mean `FileName` when you wrote `fullFileName`

Comment: and now is causing another error Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in make_video (line 25)
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);                                                                 I did edit the script based on your comment

Comment: @Neda You should try to resolve such problems yourself. The error message  itself is also very clear

Comment: It should be: `baseFileName = images{frameNumber};` (notice the brackets)